# Although value is not null, I am getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

Although return value is not null, I caught NullReferenceException at

> var currentTakipciler = TwitterCacheDepo.GetTakipciler(TemaUserID)

I looked return value in debug and it is not null but I am getting nullreferenceexception.

```
try
{
    var currentTakipciler = TwitterCacheDepo.GetTakipciler(TemaUserID);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Utils.LogYaz(ex.ToString());
}

public class TwitterCacheDepo
{
    ...
    ...

    public static Dictionary<int, string> GetTakipciler(string TemaUserID)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> returnValue = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            if (allTakipciler != null && allTakipciler.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                returnValue = allTakipciler.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime?>("BitTarih").Equals(null) && x.Field<string>("TemaUserID").Equals(TemaUserID)).ToDictionary(x => x.Field<int>("ID"), y => y.Field<string>("UserID"));// SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable("SELECT ID,TemaUserID,UserID,BitTarih FROM TBL_TwitterUserTakipciler WHERE BitTarih IS NULL SID = " + 4663);
                return returnValue;
            }
            else
            {
                allTakipciler = SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable("SELECT ID,TemaUserID,UserID,BitTarih FROM TBL_TwitterUserTakipciler WHERE SID = " + 4663);
                return allTakipciler.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime?>("BitTarih").Equals(null) && x.Field<string>("TemaUserID").Equals(TemaUserID)).ToDictionary(x => x.Field<int>("ID"), y => y.Field<string>("UserID"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.LogYaz(ex.Message.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full error message please. (In other news: Don’t just catch the general `Exception` but either specific exceptions or none).

Comment: What is not null? TwitterCacheDepo or TemaUserID?

Comment: And on what line? Perhaps `BitTarih` or `TemaUserID`, `ID` or `UserID` is null for some row?

Comment: stacktrace would be helpful...

Comment: No. TwitterCacheDepo and TemaUserID are not null. I am getting error in this line : var currentTakipciler = TwitterCacheDepo.GetTakipciler(TemaUserID).

Comment: Debug through GetTakipciler() function and see on which line exception is coming.

Comment: .NET exceptions contain stack trace information. The exception is telling you exactly where it comes from, you only neeed to look at it. (Also, you can set your debugger to stop whenever an exception is thrown: In VS.NET go to the Debug Menu >> "Exceptions..." >> "Common Language Runtime Exceptions")

Comment: @zeitgeist You catch *every exception* and just log the string in some way. That prevents you from getting any *helpful* information about the error itself. Please don’t catch for `Exception`.

Comment: There are so many places where NullReferenceException can occur, ToDictionary() requires that "ID" field must never be null for any record, When Exception thrown,Utils.LogYaz() could also internally throw this. Also instead of doing .Equals(null) try !obj.HasValue property.... Do what @zeitgeist said, post call stack or Stack Trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the full stack trace and check for the exact line number where the null ref exception was thrown from. This will give you a clear indication what happened.

To obtain the stack trace run without using a debugger, since as you say the problem isn't reproducible using a debugger.

Comment: Thank you @Vadim. I run without using a debugger,and it is working!